# Why Django ORM failing on simple foreign key relation?

Tags: django, activerecord, django-models

I'm trying to simply create `one to many` relation model of categories using Django amazing ORM.

SQL:

```
create table categories(
    id serial   primary key not null,
    parent_id   int
);
insert into categories values(default,default,default);
update categories set parent_id = 1 where id > 1;

select * from categories;
 id | parent_id
----+-----------
  2 |         1
  3 |         1
  1 |
(3 rows)
```

Django amazing orm model:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'categories'
```

Django Query:

```
Categories.objects.get(id=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column categories.parent_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "categories"."id", "categories"."parent_id_id" FROM "...
                                  ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "categories.parent_id".
```

Why it uses `parent_id_id` column instead of `parent_id` and how I can force it to use `parent_id`?

### EDIT

I just changed parent_id field to parent.

### EDIT 2

tatlar answer is not in my case becouse i already have database schema.

So after digging more deeper in documentation and other questions on stackoverflow there is what i have in result. This model contains reference to parent and children categories for each row. It could be inherited for all graph alike data models (comments, categories etc).

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=None, parent_link=True, related_name='children')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'categories'
```

Get all children for category 1:

```
from myapp.models import Categories

ch = Categories.objects.get(id=1).children print (ch)
# <QuerySet [<Categories: Categories object (2)>, <Categories: Categories object (3)>]>
```

Get parent for category 2:

```
from myapp.models import Categories

ch = Categories.objects.get(id=1).parent
print (ch)
# <Categories: Categories object (1)>
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `parent_id` Django will... just name the field `parent`

Comment: Glad you found a solution! For future reference, best SO practice is to not post your own SO *answer* in the original _question_ (it's no longer a question then!). If your own answer (in the *Answer* section) to the original question is deemed correct and upvoted by the SO community, it will become the canonical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tatlar answer is not in my case becouse i already have database schema.

So after digging more deeper in documentation and other questions on stackoverflow there is what i have in result. This `model` contains reference to `parent` and `children` categories for each row. It could be inherited for all graph alike data models (comments, categories etc).

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=None, parent_link=True, related_name='children')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'categories'
```

Get all children for category 1:

```
from myapp.models import Categories

ch = Categories.objects.get(id=1).children
print (ch)
# <QuerySet [<Categories: Categories object (2)>, <Categories: Categories object (3)>]>
```

Get parent for category 2:

```
from myapp.models import Categories

ch = Categories.objects.get(id=1).parent
print (ch)
# <Categories: Categories object (1)>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear that you are having trouble with Django. In time you may grow to love the Django ORM and how it abstracts all the SQL code for you :)

You need to dig a little deeper into how the ORM works -- it's not a 1:1 replacement for SQL code. [Check out the Model docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)

In your specific case, you need to create a new class called `Parent` and reference that class (via a `ForeignKey`) from your `Categories` class (you might also like to rename your `Categories` class to `Category` -- the ORM also handles plurals).

Try the code below (where I have already renamed `Categories` to `Category` for you):

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    # ... Extra model attributes

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"


class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # ... Extra model attributes
```

Then add all the extra attributes you need. This will create all the database tables, and their relationships, without you ever writing any SQL. If you are used to writing SQL it *is* a change, but it makes sense as you work more with the ORM and understand how good it is actually architected.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for post, but isn't Parent class will require Parent Table in database? If so i need only one table, not two.

Comment: In SQLAlchemy for example i can use primary_joins to specify any kind of relation by my self, is there something like it in django orm?

Comment: The Django ORM will **create the table and relationships for you** -- that is how it works (and one reason why its so great). You should _never_ need to create a table using SQL directly. I strongly encourage you to read the docs :)

Comment: Issue is in that i already have whole database schema, and i will not change it cos of django orm specific requirements ... easier to switch to another framework lol :)

Comment: **to specify any kind of relation by my self** actually you can have a relation with the model itself by specifying `self`